# PayPal - Simple IPN

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I've a PayPal button on my site where people can donate money. Is there a simple automated way to send the donator an email that I received the donation?

Are there any workarounds with autoresponder or anything like that?

Thanks
Michael

Comment: What's your backend? PHP? ASP/ASP.NET?

Comment: PayPal will send the user a "receipt" type email. Is that not sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

Probably enable IPN in your account and then when donor make a donation, paypal will send a notification using IPN. you should be able to get the donor email using variable payer_email in the notification and then you can send donor an email.

Comment: Is there an simple example available that works for all browser? Btw: The message PayPal sends to the payer can't be customized I guess?

Comment: How do you mean example that works for all browser? Not that im aware of the message send from paypal to the donor but you can always request this feature from paypal if you like it. you can read more about ipn at https://www.paypal.com/ipn where at the bottom, they have guide together with sample code. Shouldn't be that difficult.